# Fix Width in jQuery Dropdown Check List

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using [jQuery Dropdown Check List](http://www.gcooler.com/uploadfile/favorites/demo/dropdown-check-list.0.9/demo.html). I want to fix width of drop container to 550px but could not succeed.

I am using following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js"></script>
                <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui.dropdownchecklist.standalone.css" />
                <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui.dropdownchecklist.themeroller.css" />
                <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

                <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#mail_to").dropdownchecklist({ icon: {placement:'right'} , maxDropHeight: 550 , width:550 }); 
                </script> 

                <style type="text/css">

                   .ui-dropdownchecklist-dropcontainer
                   {   
                    width: 555px;   
                   }

                   .ui-widget-content
                   {   
                    width: 555px;   
                   }

                   .ui-widget
                   {   
                    width: 555px;   
                   }

                    </style>
```

Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: can u simulate the same on jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Please Try This Css

```
<style type="text/css">

               .ui-dropdownchecklist-dropcontainer
               {   
                width: 555px !important;  
               }

               .ui-widget-content
               {   
                width: 555px !important;  
               }

               .ui-widget
               {   
                width: 555px !important; 
               }

                </style>
```

Hope It Helps you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set width property to `.ui-dropdownchecklist-dropcontainer` , `ui-widget-content`, `ui-widget`

I made example on http://jsfiddle.net/KRzaB/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you didn't write any px, em, %...  you just have value 550 and that is it

try like this for example

```
   $("#mail_to").dropdownchecklist({ icon: {placement:'right'} , maxDropHeight: 550px ,      width:550px });
```

Comment: There is no need of px ,em etc. http://www.gcooler.com/uploadfile/favorites/demo/dropdown-check-list.0.9/demo.html