# Width setting on jQuery dropdownchecklist not being applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdownchecklist

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlone").dropdownchecklist("destroy");
    $("#ddlone").dropdownchecklist({ icon: {}, closeRadioOnClick: true, maxDropHeight: 220, width: 58 });
   });
```

I have the above peace of code and no matter what value i set for width, the dropdownchecklist remains the same. Is the way i'm doing it above there the correct way?

Comment: Have you tried checking if $("#ddlone").dropdownchecklist brings anything back in DevTools, console?

Comment: Please check this [link][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412355/fix-width-in-jquery-dropdown-check-list]

Comment: what does the console says?

Comment: Try to apply the css on the ID of your control.

Comment: no errors in the console